# How should this database be laid out/how to achieve 3NF?

Tags: sql, database, forms, layout

http://iforce.co.nz/i/v4w35nil.2sj.jpg

I need to make a Sudoku game database with the fields as provided in the diagram in 3NF. The problems is, how do I achieve 3NF with this table and how should the relationship be set up?. I've done some searching and I'm still confused.

Ignore the admin table, it's irrelevant to this question.

Thank you

Comment: Which field do you think doesn't have a functional depdancy on the pk?

Comment: The PuzzleID in the submissions table?

Comment: Really? What is the candidate key that PuzzleID depends on in the Submission table?

Comment: http://iforce.co.nz/i/3vkrq0wr.cod.jpg Would this fix the issue, or since the clue has a dependency on the difficulty, should the clue or difficulty be in a separate table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original pair of tables looks fine to me.  You have an official solution (though not, apparently, the original puzzle as set) in the `Puzzles` table.  You have Submissions which get a unique ID number and reference the Puzzle, and contain other information.

I'm not sure I understand the markings on the line, but it should be that '0 or more Submissions' can reference a given Puzzle (and that is, I think, what the left-end crow's foot indicates; I'm not sure about the H at the other end or the dashed line).

Depending on your rules, you might want a unique constraint on the email address (only one entry per contestant), or you might only need a unique constraint on 'email + timestamp' (no two entries from a single user in a single second).

But the basic table is in 5NF, and therefore in 3NF too.

Comment: Thank you for that Jonathan. So the second diagram I posted would also be in 3NF? The markings on the line for the original mean that for each puzzle there can be zero to many submissions but for each submission there can only be one puzzle.

Comment: The optionality markings are probably not correct, and there's no advantage to the second diagram compared to the first.  It's not as though a single submission is going to be posted as the answer to multiple puzzles, is it?

Comment: Okay, I'll have to check on my markings. I guess the second diagram doesn't show any advantage for the database, unless the requirements for the database were to change so that submissions were stored as per user rather than per submission. Thank you very much for your help.